# OpenLayers 3 get extent of all feature contents in a list

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I want to zoom on the extent of all the features contained in a list.

Firstly, I put my feature in a list:

```
selectedFeatures = [];    
vector2.getSource().forEachFeature(function(feature) {
                var att = feature.get("NOM");
                if (att == strUser) {
                    selectedFeatures.push(feature);
                    }
                });
```

Secondly, here my problem... i want to  zoom on the extent of all the feature on my list "selectedFeatures"

I try this but always return me an infinite extent:

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        features: selectedFeatures //add an array of features
        });

var dataExtent = vectorSource.getExtent();
map.getView().fitExtent(dataExtent, map.getSize())
console.log("Extents : " + dataExtent);
```

Someone have a solution to get the extent of features contained in a list ?

Comment: Actually `vectorSource.getExtent()` should work fine. Might there be a problem with the coordinates of your features?

Comment: There is something wrong with my selectedFeatures. I'M able to get the extent of each feature but once i put them on my list "selectedFeatures" I have problem to get information on this feature. 

May be I do something wrong when I add feature on a new Vector Source ?? (My data is a GeoJSON format)

Comment: Maybe you could create a JSFiddle with a handful of features that you have this problem with?

Comment: Knowing what version of OpenLayers 3 you are using may be useful as well.

Comment: I have the version 3.4.0 and i will look for a JSFiddle, I never played with it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should do the trick?

```
var extent = features[0].getGeometry().getExtent().slice(0);
features.forEach(function(feature){ ol.extent.extend(extent,feature.getGeometry().getExtent())});
```

Comment: May be updated to use a for loop that skip the first element in the iteration step

Comment: "Features" = my list of feature (selectedFeatures)?
If it's the case, it didn't work at your first line. It's telling me getExtent() is not a function.

Comment: Sorry, was a bit too quick on copy pasting.  Remember to do checks that features has more than 0 element and such.

Answer (score 1):

There is `boundingExtent` function created for this need:

```
const selectedFeatures = vector2.getSource().getFeatures()
  .filter((feature) => feature.get('NOM') == strUser)

const bounds = ol.extent.boundingExtent(selectedFeatures)

map.getView().fit(bounds)
```

I haven't actually tested the code, but you get the idea.

Comment: `boundingExtent` is taking an array of coordinates as parameter : https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_extent.html#.boundingExtent